# how to replace href url of html tags with incomplete attribute in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML :

```
<p><a href='http://download.onlagump3.com/bokep.php?search=Kehna+Hi+Kya+++Drishti+Garg' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 1</font></a></p>
<br />      <p><a href='http://www.myfreemp3.cc/mp3/Kehna+Hi+Kya+++Drishti+Garg' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 2</font></a></p>
<br />      <p><a href='http://mp3skull.com/mp3/Kehna_Hi_Kya___Drishti_Garg.html' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 3</font></a></p>
<br />      <p><a href='http://www.stafaband.info/download/mp3/lagu_Kehna_Hi_Kya___Drishti_Garg/' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 4</font></a></p>
<br />      <p><a href='https://www.google.com/#q=site:4shared.com+Kehna+Hi+Kya+++Drishti+Garg' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 5</font></a></p>
<br />
```

JQUERY :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $("a").click(function(e){
           var url1 = $(this).attr('href');
           var url = url1.replace(url1,'http://alfanetcell.hostoi.com/phpwidget/download.php?type=int&link='+url1);
           //$('#result').replaceWith( "<div id='result'>" + url + "</div>" );
var newurl = $('a[href="'+url1+'"]').attr("href", url);
             $('a[href="'+url1+'"]').$(this).attr("target", "_blank");
           return false;
        });
    });
```

I want to replace all link in html above with `http://alfanetcell.hostoi.com/phpwidget/download.php?type=int&link='+url1` when the script that I enter into my blog and then all the links in my blog be changed by the script (i'am sorry, My English is very difficult !)

**UPDATE** !, thank's for all my friends, I have found the solution of this discussion:

```
     $("p a").click(function(e){
           var url1 = $(this).attr('href');
           var url = url1.replace(url1,'http://alfanetcell.hostoi.com/phpwidget/download.php?type=int&link='+url1);
           //$('#result').replaceWith( "<div id='result'>" + url + "</div>" );
var newurl = $('a[href="'+url1+'"]').attr("href", url);
             $('a[href="'+url1+'"]').$(this).attr("target", "_blank");
           return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: im not sure i understand what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Because your selector `a` targets all anchor elements in the page,

Instead you can add a class `download` to those `anchro` elements you want to change like

```
<p><a class="download" href='http://download.onlagump3.com/bokep.php?search=Kehna+Hi+Kya+++Drishti+Garg' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 1</font></a></p>
<br />      
<p><a class="download" href='http://www.myfreemp3.cc/mp3/Kehna+Hi+Kya+++Drishti+Garg' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 2</font></a></p>
<br />      
<p><a class="download" href='http://mp3skull.com/mp3/Kehna_Hi_Kya___Drishti_Garg.html' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 3</font></a></p>
<br />      
<p><a class="download" href='http://www.stafaband.info/download/mp3/lagu_Kehna_Hi_Kya___Drishti_Garg/' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 4</font></a></p>
<br />      
<p><a class="download" href='https://www.google.com/#q=site:4shared.com+Kehna+Hi+Kya+++Drishti+Garg' target='_blank'><font color='blue' size='4'>DOWNLOAD From Server 5</font></a></p>
<br />
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".download a").click(function(e){
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://alfanetcell.hostoi.com/phpwidget/download.php?type=int&link='+$(this).attr('href')).attr("target", "_blank");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank's before Arun P Johny, I may not be to change the HTML code one by one and I want to change it just with a jquery script, because it is in the html code in any of my blog posts

Comment: @AlfaNetCell then can we target all `anchro` elements with the text `DOWNLOAD From Server`

Comment: thanks for the response, the html code stored in each of my blog posts that number has hundreds of posts, so I may not change one by one, so I just wanted to change it to a jquery code alone, and I still do not know how

Comment: unless you can define how to identify these anchor elements there is nothing much that can be done

Comment: @AlfaNetCell one thing you can try is changing `$(".download a")` to `$("p > a:contains('Download')")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something more straight-forward like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e){
    var old_url = $(this).attr('href');
    var new_url = 'http://alfanetcell.hostoi.com/phpwidget/download.php?type=int&link=' + old_url;
    $(this).attr('href', new_url);
    return true;
 });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx4ghmag/)

Note this will cause issues if the link is clicked multiple times because it will take the modified url as the old url, and keep appending to itself each time you click. Not sure what the intended behaviour is so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: thank's before Superfly, but when I click a link one by one, a link not open in new tab but just replace link only

Comment: You can simply `return true;` to achieve that. I'll update my answer.